# Expo Google Sign In: Error 400: invalid_request

Tags: android, react-native, expo, google-oauth, google-signin

I am working on a React Native for iOS, Android and Web. Earlier this year my colleague responsible for the Android side of things had issues with Google Sign In, and their solution was to remove it entirely.

I am now trying to re-implement this. I have no issues on Web or iOS, but with Android, I get the following error:

> Error 400: invalid_request
> You can't sign in to this app because it does not comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure. 
> You can let the app developer know that this app doesn't comply with one or more Google validation rules.

It then says in the `Request Details` section:

> If you're the app developer, make sure that these request details comply with Google's policies.
>
> - redirect_uri: exp://192.*.*.*:19000

I have checked my `app.json` to ensure my credentials match up with both my Google Cloud Console API credentials as well as Firebase credentials.

I have followed Expo's documentation, and I have done everything correctly on Web and iOS.

Any help would be appreciated, and if more information is needed just let me know. Thanks

**EDIT**

I did go into my `Authorised redirect URIs` and try to add `exp://192.*.*.*:19000` but it will not allow me to.

Comment: redirect uri needs to be a valid web address with https

Comment: @DalmTo yeah I understand that, but my Android is using the URI ``exp://192.*.*.*:19000`` so I am not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: did you ever figure this out, I'm stuck and just tried the exact same thing... entering exp://192.*.*.*:19000 into authorized redirect uris and it wouldn't accept it.

Comment: @TreyCollier Find any solution for this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:** You cant use `exp://192.*.*.*:19000` as a redirect uri with web application credentials.  It must be Redirect URIs must use the HTTPS scheme, Hosts cannot be raw IP addresses, Redirect URIs cannot contain certain characters including: Wildcard characters ('*')

## Background info.

There are serval types of client types for google authorization.

1. web
2. mobile
3. native (Desktop)
4. service account.

Each of these types use a slightingly different type of authorization.  Installed applications have to return the authorization back to where it came from or localhost.   Web applications, the authorization is returned to a valid web address.

The redirect uri in the case of web apps and installed apps is used to tell the authorization server where it is allowed to send the authorization code back to.  This is a security measure to ensure that no one can hijack your authorization, by just adding any redirect uri.

> You can't sign in to this app because it does not comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure.

This error message is telling you that the redirect uri your application is sending is not a valid redirect uir.
[Redirect URI validation rules](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#uri-validation)

you are probably getting stuck by these

[image]

your redirect URI `exp://192.*.*.*:19000` is not https and its an ip address. neither of which is going to be allowed.

In the case of mobile apps things are completely different.  This form of authorization normally use's the package name and an SHA-1 in order to authorize the user and return the token back properly.

I dont see how you are going to get that to work with react.

Comment: And what I'm supposed to do if i'm using an Android Client Id (Not a Web Client Id), that I have already registered inside the Google Cloud Console with it's package name and it's SHA-1 fingerprint but still getting the error? I'm receiving the exact same error and my redirect uri also begins with exp://...
[This section of the API docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/guides/authorization/installed-apps#step-2:-send-a-request-to-googles-oauth-2.0-server) that i'm trying to integrate with my app says that the redirect_uri must begin with com.example.myapp://...

Comment: Hi Linda, I am using IOS, but still getting the same redirect URL error. can you please help out in IOS?

Comment: You might want to check the oauth docs for mobile apps [Ios](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#ios) my understanding is you need an SHA-1 key but you need the correct code for using it.

Comment: Has anyone been able to make this work with version 5.0.2?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work by setting

1. setting scheme in app.json to value of android.package from the same file:

```
"expo": {
    "scheme": "com.something.somethingelse"
```

2. setting Google.useIdTokenAuthRequest like

```
const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useIdTokenAuthRequest(
        {
            clientId: 'myandroid-token.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        },
        { native: 'com.something.somethingelse://' }
    );
```

the clientId has to be android client id, not web id

Answer (score 0):

If you use the "expo-auth-session" library, try to change version to "^4.0.3". It helped me.

Comment: import * as AuthSession from 'expo-auth-session';

const signin = async () => {
  const redirectUri = AuthSession.getRedirectUrl();
  const response = await AuthSession.startAsync({
  authUrl: 
  `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=${EXPO_CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&response_type=token&scope=openid%20profile%20email`
  });
 };
 
It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to "expo-auth-session": "~4.0.3" resolved my issue.

```
import * as Google from 'expo-auth-session/providers/google'
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser'
WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession()

export const GoogleLoginButton = () => {
  // Replace actual IDs with placeholders
  const googleAuthConfig = {
    iosClientId: '<IOS_CLIENT_ID>',
    androidClientId: '<ANDROID_CLIENT_ID>',
    webClientId: '<WEB_CLIENT_ID>'
  }

  const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest(googleAuthConfig)

  return (
    <Button
      title='Sign in with Google'
      onPress={() => promptAsync()}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I did not have the **Custom URI Scheme activated**, I activated it and it worked, it is strange because before it worked for me without having it activated lol

Comment: Activate custom URI scheme in Google console

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add that its important that the scheme has the same name as the bundleidentifier. Once I did that, google login worked.